# Facebook's Graph API doesn't deliver full sized images although accessor is named "full_picture" — How to get the real full picture?

Tags: image, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.6

I am aware of the many existing questions about [FB's Graph API and how to retrieve full sized images](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[facebook-graph-api]%20full_picture).

But many of them are about getting user profile pictures, those are answered with "/<userid>/picture" or anything similar. I need to know how to get posted images from a page feed, so this is not what I'm looking for. Then there are questions answered with "use `full_image` in your search query".

Well, at this point my problem begins. `full_image` actually isn't the full image. It's limited to 720x720 pixels.

Let's have a look at an example:
[explore this picture from SPIEGEL ONLINE](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895?method=GET&path=38246844868_10154299256109869%3Ffields%3Dfull_picture%2Cpicture%2Cpermalink_url%2Ctype%2Cobject_id&version=v2.6) in Facebook's Graph API explorer.

The given path for the Graph API request is:

```
/38246844868_10154299256109869?fields=full_picture,picture,permalink_url,type,object_id
```

The response is the following:

```
{
  "full_picture": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/13450864_1068539139897737_5236884236245491903_n.jpg?oh=20cc415e7931b8eb8a6228ab253bfa53&oe=57E23B8B",
  "picture": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/s130x130/13450864_1068539139897737_5236884236245491903_n.jpg?oh=37c4263e047f841da7243c040a4f279d&oe=57C6469E",
  "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/spiegelonline/posts/10154299256109869",
  "type": "photo",
  "object_id": "1068539139897737",
  "id": "38246844868_10154299256109869"
}
```

As you can see I requested the `picture` (which is just a thumb) and the full size image indexed by `full_picture`. Unfortunately this picture is **not full**, but a resized one instead. It's even mentioned in the image's URL that it's only 720x720 at max.

Here it is: [https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/**s720x720**/13450864_1068539139897737_5236884236245491903_n.jpg?oh=20cc415e7931b8eb8a6228ab253bfa53&oe=57E23B8B](https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/13450864_1068539139897737_5236884236245491903_n.jpg?oh=20cc415e7931b8eb8a6228ab253bfa53&oe=57E23B8B)

When visiting the Facebook page behind the `permalink_url` you get to the image post.

Here we go: https://www.facebook.com/spiegelonline/posts/10154299256109869

When opening the posted image in fullscreen mode and then right-clicking it to show the image file you will see that the image will be much larger that 720x720.

There it is: https://scontent-frt3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-8/13422344_1068539139897737_5236884236245491903_o.jpg

Please, compare the URL with the one responded by the API endpoint as shown above. Even the servers are different. So, there isn't an easy solution by replacing "_n" with "_o" as mention in several other questions here on SO.

My question is: How do I get the full size image URL using Graph API?

**TL;DR:** Facebook's Graph API seems to deliver resized images posted to a page's feed by accessing them with `full_image`. So, how to retrieve the actual full (meaning non-resized) image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution after playing around again with the Graph API Explorer. And it's much simpler than I thought.

All you need to do is the following few steps:

1. Just request this path (this time without the `full_picture` accessor, only the `object_id` is important here):

[`/38246844868_10154299256109869?fields=object_id`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895?method=GET&path=38246844868_10154299256109869%3Ffields%3Dobject_id)

2. Grab the `object_id` from the API's response:

```js
{
  "object_id": "1068539139897737",
  "id": "38246844868_10154299256109869"
}
```

In this example it's `"1068539139897737"`.

3. Now, request all `images` for the above `object_id`:

[`/1068539139897737?fields=images`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895?method=GET&path=1068539139897737%3Ffields%3Dimages)

4. The response is a JSON like this:

```js
{
  "images": [
    {
      "height": 2048,
      "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/13422344_1068539139897737_5236884236245491903_o.jpg?oh=e923e167d258e77c12caf422d98b44aa&oe=59968118",
      "width": 1536
    },
    {
      "height": 1280,
      "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/p960x960/13422344_1068539139897737_5236884236245491903_o.jpg?oh=7a5086e29957b222c2fd1136f3640c98&oe=598633CD",
      "width": 960
    },
    // … many others in between here …
    {
      "height": 225,
      "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p75x225/13450864_1068539139897737_5236884236245491903_n.jpg?oh=26d94247c4e34a69fb0db3fb1ae213b5&oe=599353F9",
      "width": 168
    }
  ],
  "id": "1068539139897737"
}
```

5. From the `images` list which is down-sorted by size just grab the very first entry. Get its `source` – et voilà – this is the full picture.

Comment: …I'm not sure why the JSON responses are not formatted properly with code style. Any ideas?

Comment: @fepegar …just a simple comment before the code block? it could have been so simple. ;) thank you.